# URI for actions of services

Tags: services, uri

I have defined the following service.

```
'salesforce_subscriptions' => array(
    'operations' => array(
      'delete' => array(
        'help' => 'Remove subscriptions from SalesForce',
        ...
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'ids',
            'type' => 'string',
            'description' => '',
            'source' => array('param' => 'ids'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
          array(
            'name' => 'API key',
            'optional' => FALSE,
            'type' => 'string',
            'description' => 'The api key',
            'source' => array('param' => 'api_key'),
          ),
        )
      )
    ),
```

How can I access this? 
The endpoint of the service is: endpoint.
I can access the index service by:
www.example.com/endpoint/salesforce_subscriptions

How can I access delete?

Comment: I would guess www.example.com/endpoint/salesforce_subscriptions/delete.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access it via

```
www.example.com/endpoint/salesforce_subscriptions/[ids]/delete
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to experiment with the id parameter source, e.g path argument vs param

For more info and example, see the node resource definition here:

[`_node_resource_definition`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!services!resources!node_resource.inc/function/_node_resource_definition/7)